# How do I override a template file in a Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to override a template file in WooCommerce products slider plugin. The path for the PHP-file is plugins/woocommerce-products-slider/templates/wcps-title.php

How can I do this?

I've tried to do the same path structure in my child theme, but it doesn't work.

This is the code from the original file:

```
<?php 

/** 
* @Author         ParaTheme 
* Copyright:     2015 ParaTheme 
*/ 

if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) exit;  // if direct access  

  $title_text = apply_filters( 'wcps_filter_title', get_the_title(get_the_ID()) ); 

  $html.= '<div class="wcps-items-title" >
      <a style="color:'.$wcps_items_title_color.';font-size:'.$wcps_items_title_font_size.'" href="'.$permalink.'">
        '.$title_text.'
      </a>
  </div>';
```

And I want to add `<span class="set-field">'. get_field('set') .'</span>` to the code so it looks like:

```
<?php 

/** 
* @Author         ParaTheme 
* Copyright:     2015 ParaTheme 
*/ 

if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) exit;  // if direct access  

  $title_text = apply_filters( 'wcps_filter_title', get_the_title(get_the_ID()) ); 

  $html.= '<div class="wcps-items-title" >
      <a style="color:'.$wcps_items_title_color.';font-size:'.$wcps_items_title_font_size.'" href="'.$permalink.'">
        <span class="set-field">
            '. get_field('set') .'
        </span>
        '.$title_text.'
      </a>
  </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use a function in my plugin file to handle specific templates to prevent it being overwritten.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'assign_template');

function assign_template($template){
    if($template == 'old_template.php'){
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce-products-slider/wcps-title-custom.php';
   }
   return $template;
}
```

Comment: Hi KGreene and thank you for your reply :) When I use this function the website dont work. It only shows a message "The site is experiencing technical difficulties."

Comment: oops. remove the "public"

Comment: Hmm it still doesnt seem to overwrite the old template.

Comment: You can try changing the priority add_filter( 'template_include', 'assign_template', 100, 1);

Comment: Stil dont work. Is it maybe because of my path structure for the new template file? It looks like this /child-theme/woocommerce-products-slider/wcps-title-custom.php and so far my code look like this in my functions-php:

add_filter( 'template_include', 'assign_template', 100, 1);

function assign_template($template){
    if($template == 'wcps-title.php'){
        $template = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . 'wcps-title-custom.php';
   }
   return $template;
}

Comment: gottca, the code i posted was using a plugin_dir_path. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It still didnt work :( But i found out another way to add the field. I found a filter hook on the plugins website and made this code:
add_filter('wcps_filter_title', 'wcps_filter_title_extra' );
    
function wcps_filter_title_extra($title){
// you can use get_the_id() function for loop product id.
$product_id = get_the_id();
  
  return $html.= '
      
        <span class="set-field">
            '. get_field('set') .'
        </span>
        '.$title.'
  ';
  
  }
It's maybe not the best way, but it works for now. I appreciate very much your help. Thank you :)